# How to execute a .bat file from node.js passing some parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-file

I use node.js v4.4.4 and I need to run a `.bat` file from node.js.

From the location of the js file for my node app the .bat is runnable using command line with the following path (Window platform):

```
'../src/util/buildscripts/build.bat --profile ../profiles/app.profile.js'
```

But when using node I cannot run it, no specific error are thrown.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

```
    var ls = spawn('cmd.exe', ['../src/util/buildscripts', 'build.bat', '--profile ../profiles/app.profile.js']);

    ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });

    ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    });

    ls.on('exit', function (code) {
        console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    });
```

Comment: Related: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows

Comment: Related: https://medium.com/@graeme_boy/how-to-optimize-cpu-intensive-work-in-node-js-cdc09099ed41#.zbzjytwzw

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following script solved my issue, basically I had to:

- Converting to absolute path reference to .bat file.
- Passing arguments to .bat using an array.

  ```
  var bat = require.resolve('../src/util/buildscripts/build.bat');
  var profile = require.resolve('../profiles/app.profile.js');
  var ls = spawn(bat, ['--profile', profile]);

  ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + data);
  });

  ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('stderr: ' + data);
  });

  ls.on('exit', function (code) {
      console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
  });
  ```

Below a list of useful relevant articles:

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_asynchronous_process_creation

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2266928

Answer (score 27):

You should be able to run a command like this:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

child_process.exec('path_to_your_executables', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

Comment: May I ask you... why do you use .exec instead of spawn?

Comment: Using spawn with shell options set is the same as exec. Documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows)

Comment: Are you sure? Accordingly to this docs they are different, and I need to use spawn if possible insted of exec. You could please add a spawn solution on your answer? http://www.hacksparrow.com/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child_process.html

Comment: Taken from the documentation: "When running on Windows, .bat and .cmd files can be invoked using child_process.spawn() with the shell option set, with child_process.exec(), or by spawning cmd.exe and passing the .bat or .cmd file as an argument (which is what the shell option and child_process.exec() do)" followed by an example right after that sentence

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately I am not able to make it run as I need to pass the following parameters --profile ../profiles/app.profile.js.. are you able to modify your answer with an example? I would be glad to accept it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try `child_process.exec("../src/util/buildscripts/build.bat --profile ../profiles/app.profile.js"), function....`

Comment: Thanks, but does not work, paths must be resolved to absolute first for my understanding.

Comment: Use `path` module then. You should be able to resolve to that file using `path.join` and `__dirname` variable

Comment: I was able to solve my issue as posted below. Thanks anyways for your time on this issue :).

Comment: No problem. Glad to help