# How to run windows cmd.exe commands from javascript code run on node bash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there a way where I can invoke a windows batch file from inside the javascript code? Or any other healthy way to do the below through any node package?

scripts.bat

```
 ECHO "JAVASCRIPT is AWESOME"
  PAUSE
```

scripts.js

```
// Code to read and run the batch file //
```

On the command prompt:

```
C:/> node scripts.js
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a .bat file from node.js passing some parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601121/how-to-execute-a-bat-file-from-node-js-passing-some-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with child_process.  You just have to pass the file you want to execute.

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
const child = execFile('scripts.bat', [], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```